How do I add a computed column to an SQLModel table?
I am using SQLModel together with FastAPI and I have the models Package and Downloads, where a Package has multiple Downloads which in turn have a count field. My goal is to add up the Download.counts associated to each package in a query like this:
SELECT package.name, SUM(download.count) as download_total
  FROM package
  LEFT JOIN download ON (download.package_id = package.id)
  GROUP BY package.name

and return a model instance (e. g. PackagePublic) including the column downloads_total, so I can use it as a FastAPI reponse model, about like this:
@app.get("/packages", response_model=list[PackagePublic])
def packages(session: Session=Annotated[Session, Depends(session)]):
    statement = select(PackagePublic).join(Download)
    return session.exec(statement).all()

These are my models:
class PackageBase(SQLModel): ...

class Package(PackageBase, table=True):
    id: int | None = Field(default=None, primary_key=True)
    downloads: list["Download"] = Relationship(back_populates="package")

class PackagePublic(PackageBase):
    id: int
    downloads: list["Download"] = []
    downloads_total: int  # <- not a database column

class Download(SQLModel, table=True):
    id: int | None = Field(default=None, primary_key=True)
    package_id: int = Field(foreign_key="package.id")
    package: Package = Relationship(back_populates="downloads")
    downloads: int

I tried adjusting the query (statement = select(Package, func.sum(Download.count).label("downloads_total")).join(Download).group_by(Package.id)), but this way I cannot return a FastAPI response model. I also tried adding a computed field to either the Package or PackagePublic model (using column_property), but failed completely.
I’d be happy with either adjusting the query or adding a "virtual" field (like PackagePublic.downloads_total in the code above) to the model.
